# Transfer applicants. Who are they?

Tags: application, undergraduate, transfer-student

Who are transfer applicants? 
I was applying for undergraduate program in a university and there I saw a transfer applicants category. I want to know what does that mean?

Comment: As an example from the radio, students who go to Northern Virginia Community College and complete 2 years of courses can transfer to the University of Virginia to finish their 4-year degree.

Comment: Out of interest, how successful are they? I have this vague idea that switching schools would be frowned on without a really good reason..

Comment: @JPJanet It's not that uncommon, and doesn't always happen for some extraordinary reason (for instance, plenty of people go to community college, which is only 2 years, and then graduate and have to transfer to get a bachelor's).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Applicants who have already begun their undergraduate education at another institution and wish to transfer into this one.

Comment: The most common case in the US would be that they started at a community college and then transferred to a four-year school.